# DataGrid throws NullReferenceException

Tags: wpf, exception, datagrid, tabcontrol

I have an application that displays a few datagrids in the tabitems of a TabControl. On one of the machines on which it's deployed - and only one - switching tabs crashes the application without any warning.
I have no way to debug the app on that machine. The only indication I have on the crash comes from the event viewer. Here's the exception stack trace:

> Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated
>   due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   System.NullReferenceException Stack:    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader.SetLeftGripperVisibility()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader.HookupGripperEvents()
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.MeasureChild(System.Windows.UIElement,
>   System.Windows.Size)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.GenerateChild(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IItemContainerGenerator,
>   System.Windows.Size, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn, Int32
>   ByRef, System.Windows.Size ByRef)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.GenerateChild(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IItemContainerGenerator,
>   System.Windows.Size, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn,
>   System.IDisposable ByRef, Int32 ByRef, System.Windows.Size ByRef)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.DetermineRealizedColumnsBlockList(System.Windows.Size)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)    at
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()    at
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(System.Object)
>   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(System.Object) 
>   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32)    at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode,
>   CleanupCode, System.Object)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr,
>   IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)    at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr,
>   Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32)    at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
>   System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
>   at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG
>   ByRef)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run()    at MyApp.App.Main()

It all happens in external code.
I tries to inherit from DataGrid, override the ApplyTemplate method and putting a try catch in it. But it seems this is not allowed and the resulting control is unusable.
Any suggestions on how to fix this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug and you should contact microsoft support team. but there's another option you can give it a try.

[Here](http://referencesource-beta.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/DataGridColumnHeader.cs.html#57db82e831124e14#references#references) you can find the beta version of DataGridColumnHeader source code.

### Edit

According to that source code my guess is if you turn off the column resize or anything related to column header's "Grip" area it might no longer throw the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Once I derive from DataGridColumnHeader how do I get the DataGrid to use the derived version?

Comment: You are right I didn't check that first. What I meant was to create a set of custom `DataGridColumn`s with custom headers. but unfortunately it can't be done. sorry for misleading you. I updated my answer see if it's helpful.

Comment: No worries. I'll try to disable the resize, but that's too restrictive I'm afraid...

Comment: If that didn't work or caused more trouble, try reinstalling .net framework or other prerequisites on that machine. or even upgrading to the latest OS may help.

Comment: Disabling column resize has work for now though it's not an ideal solution. I'll do some tests with .net 4.5 hoping it will be fixed.